# Google Maps turned upside down

Tags: android, google-maps, screenshot

## The problem

I have just got a bizarre bug report from one of my Android users - the embedded Google Map appeared upside down:

[image]

## Context & Scope

- The app is multilingual. The user was using the Spanish interface.
- It happened only once (as far as I know).
- The map icons are upside down, too - for example the little gray icon between `de` and `mapas` in the lower part of the picture on the right hand side.
- I have Googled the issue, bug found nothing relevant - most discussions discuss issues in the Maps App, not API.

**Any idea why the map is upside down, and how to prevent this from happening in the future?**

Comment: Are you forcing a particular orientation in your app?

Comment: Hmm, I might be wrong as the other screen elements are clearly the right way up but there are 4 main orientations - portrait, inverse portrait, landscape and inverse landscape. Is the map a part of the main layout or a Fragment added separately? I'm just guessing really - perhaps the phone was being held as inverse portrait, the main layout rotated but the map was forced to portrait (or the other way around). Not sure what to suggest.